# Grails render view in not rendering view

Tags: grails, view, render

I am working on a web application,in which from a domain i want to render a view on browser.

My requirement is something like this-

When user comes to my website for registration,after he submits  data from controller i render a different view.

I am using

```
render(view:'myviewname')
```

but it not working and gives error invocation target exception and control goes to some other method of same controller.
 i also try using PageRendrar and by creating separate method for render my view but in all case finding same issue.

Code -if have tried using different ways but all are not working for me.

```
def mytest(){
   render(view:'mytest')
}


def mytest(){
   render(view:'/book/myview')
   return
}

def mytest(){
  render(view:'/error')
}
```

UPDATED:

> WARN: Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java‌​:107)
>   at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInter‌​ceptor.java:1260)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code and stacktrace

Comment: @lgor Artamonov i have added my code

Comment: and stacktrace please

Comment: staktrace is - WARN: Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:107)
 at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1260)

Comment: It's not clear where this exception are thrown, can't see any line related to you controller, just standard classes. Are you sure that it's actual stacktrace? (and please, put it into original question)

Comment: @ravi You can always edit your question adding more info. Try to put the full stacktrace, this will help us to see what's going on :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. If i write:

```
def abc(){
    render (view:'/DG/quanlyCCDG')
}
```

I have the same WARN like you got. But if i write :

```
def abc(){
    def ccdgList = CCDG.findAllByCheckDel(0)
    render (view:'/DG/quanlyCCDG',model:[ccdgList:ccdgList])
}
```

I didnt get any WARN (?). May be you can not write only `render view` in a method ?? Im not sure, but if you write like above, i think it will be ok. Sorry my English is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code, May be it will help you.

```
def mytest(){
render(view:'../book/myview')
return
}
```